# "Give me a break!"

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "Give me a break" in German?

> Give me a break, give me a week to get a job!

My translation:

> Verschon mich, gib mir eine Woche um einen Job zu bekommen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your translation is right so far.
(Well for written language it would be "Verschone")

Another possible versions are:

> Gönne mir eine Pause, lasse mir eine Woche Zeit einen Beruf (Job) zu finden (bekommen)!

Hope that helps :)

Comment: "Beruf" is the wrong word here. It's not about choosing a profession but an employment. So "Arbeitsplatz", "Stelle", "Arbeit" or "Job" are possible translations.

Comment: Why do you need the *e* in written German? I was under the impression the *e* is used as hypercorrection, and is an optional lengthening of the base-form...